# Merging on common column values in Pandas produces incorrect dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am attempting to merge 2 dataframes in pandas based on a common column. Reading the documentation on merging, everything I am doing implicates that the dataframes should merge on the columns specified, while only keeping common values. It certainly keeps the common values, but produces a massive dataframe that is essentially an entire "right" dataframe for every index in the "left" dataframe.

My left dataframe is

```
left
Out[325]: 
     A   B   C   D MergeThis
0   38  43  20  34       -N2
1   14  44  23  91       -N2
2   55  50  30  92       -N2
3   29  20  56   0       -N2
4   61   6  38  44       -N2
5   18  61  30   7       -N2
6   67  45  60  81       -N2
7    7  53  60  72       +N2
8   15  46   0  82       +N2
9    6  90  83  36       +N2
10   0  87  64  82       +N2
11  13  22  13  39       +N2
12  65  88  50  34       +N2
13  35  31  72  34       +N2
```

and my right data frame is

```
right
Out[326]: 
    E   F   G   H MergeThis
0  22  81  97  28       +N2
1  20   4  44  48       +N2
2  19  41  52  25       +N2
3  30  37  66  24       +N2
4  32  40  56  92       +N2
5  95  76  91  31       +N2
6  36  66  17  85       +N2
```

Obviously, I am attempting to merge on the "MergeThis" column, such that I end up with the *+N2* values combined, with the columns from both "left" and "right". However, what I end up with is something strange:

```
left.merge(right, on='MergeThis')
Out[327]: 
     A   B   C   D MergeThis   E   F   G   H
0    7  53  60  72       +N2  22  81  97  28
1    7  53  60  72       +N2  20   4  44  48
2    7  53  60  72       +N2  19  41  52  25
3    7  53  60  72       +N2  30  37  66  24
4    7  53  60  72       +N2  32  40  56  92
5    7  53  60  72       +N2  95  76  91  31
6    7  53  60  72       +N2  36  66  17  85
7   15  46   0  82       +N2  22  81  97  28
8   15  46   0  82       +N2  20   4  44  48
9   15  46   0  82       +N2  19  41  52  25
10  15  46   0  82       +N2  30  37  66  24
11  15  46   0  82       +N2  32  40  56  92
12  15  46   0  82       +N2  95  76  91  31
13  15  46   0  82       +N2  36  66  17  85
14   6  90  83  36       +N2  22  81  97  28
15   6  90  83  36       +N2  20   4  44  48
16   6  90  83  36       +N2  19  41  52  25
17   6  90  83  36       +N2  30  37  66  24
18   6  90  83  36       +N2  32  40  56  92
19   6  90  83  36       +N2  95  76  91  31
20   6  90  83  36       +N2  36  66  17  85
21   0  87  64  82       +N2  22  81  97  28
22   0  87  64  82       +N2  20   4  44  48
23   0  87  64  82       +N2  19  41  52  25
24   0  87  64  82       +N2  30  37  66  24
25   0  87  64  82       +N2  32  40  56  92
26   0  87  64  82       +N2  95  76  91  31
27   0  87  64  82       +N2  36  66  17  85
28  13  22  13  39       +N2  22  81  97  28
29  13  22  13  39       +N2  20   4  44  48
30  13  22  13  39       +N2  19  41  52  25
31  13  22  13  39       +N2  30  37  66  24
32  13  22  13  39       +N2  32  40  56  92
33  13  22  13  39       +N2  95  76  91  31
34  13  22  13  39       +N2  36  66  17  85
35  65  88  50  34       +N2  22  81  97  28
36  65  88  50  34       +N2  20   4  44  48
37  65  88  50  34       +N2  19  41  52  25
38  65  88  50  34       +N2  30  37  66  24
39  65  88  50  34       +N2  32  40  56  92
40  65  88  50  34       +N2  95  76  91  31
41  65  88  50  34       +N2  36  66  17  85
42  35  31  72  34       +N2  22  81  97  28
43  35  31  72  34       +N2  20   4  44  48
44  35  31  72  34       +N2  19  41  52  25
45  35  31  72  34       +N2  30  37  66  24
46  35  31  72  34       +N2  32  40  56  92
47  35  31  72  34       +N2  95  76  91  31
48  35  31  72  34       +N2  36  66  17  85
```

Which has essentially created a duplicate dataframe for every index of my "right" dataframe.

On the one hand, I know how to do another workaround to get the dataframe I want with more code and breaking up one of the dataframes a bit more so that the merge is "prettier". However, I really want to know WHY this is happening? I want to be able to use the merge functionality in the future, but I don't fully understand what pandas is trying to do to produce this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the data frame you want look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result looks correct. The join criteria is for every row of `left` with `MergeThis` equal to `+N2` to be joined to each row of `right` that has that matching condition. There are 7 such rows in each of the data frames, resulting in 49 rows for the cartesian product of row sets in the output.

Note that the merge type for `DataFrame.merge` are `left`, `right`, `inner` and `outer`, which determine *the set of keys to use for the join*, not a restriction on which rows will match to which other rows. The default of `inner` just means to use the intersection of values contained in the join column(s) between `left` and `right`, which will just be `+N2` anyway. If you used `right` you'd get the same result since the right DataFrame contains only `+N2` for this column. Likewise, if you used `left` or `outer` they would happen to be the same as each other in this case, because either would cause the possible match set to be based on either `-N2` or `+N2` and you'd get the 49 rows from all pairwise matches of `+N2` plus the other rows for `-N2` (but with not additional matches for them, and `NaN` values for the columns that would come from `right` in that case).

From the sound of it, you might have expected the 7 rows of `+N2` in `right` to just be attached to `left` with `NaN` filled in for the other rows. To achieve this, you should use *concatenation* not merge-based joining.

Here's an example with similar toy data using `pandas.concat` (you can just remove the extra `MergeThis` column when you're done),

```
In [42]: right
Out[42]:
   C  D MergeThis
0  1  2       +N2
1  3  4       +N2
2  5  6       +N2
3  7  8       +N2

In [43]: left
Out[43]:
    A   B MergeThis
0   1   2       -N2
1   3   4       -N2
2   5   6       +N2
3   7   8       +N2
4   9  10       +N2
5  11  12       +N2

In [44]: right.index = left[left.MergeThis == '+N2'].index.values

In [45]: right
Out[45]:
   C  D MergeThis
2  1  2       +N2
3  3  4       +N2
4  5  6       +N2
5  7  8       +N2

In [46]: pandas.concat([left, right], axis=1)
Out[46]:
    A   B MergeThis    C    D MergeThis
0   1   2       -N2  NaN  NaN       NaN
1   3   4       -N2  NaN  NaN       NaN
2   5   6       +N2  1.0  2.0       +N2
3   7   8       +N2  3.0  4.0       +N2
4   9  10       +N2  5.0  6.0       +N2
5  11  12       +N2  7.0  8.0       +N2
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the solution. My plan was to us concat if I could not figure it out, and it seems I was right. A followup question to this is that the "merge" command in the documentation appears to create the desired output (or something similar). Is this because the "key" column contains a unique value for each index? [K0, K1, K2].